# How to send a RichTextBox as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, reference, richtextbox

OK, I am new to c# so what i want to do is i am creating a class that works with a richtextbox object and so the user is suppose to create an instance of my class and associate it with a RichTextBox in their own form by calling the method SetRTB(RichTextBox NewRTB)
so what i have is this

```
public class RichTB_Color
{
    public RichTextBox TextF; // a copy of the user's richtext box

    public RichTB_Color()
    {
    }
    public bool SetRichTextBox(RichTextBox To)
    {
        if (To == null)     // if object is null return false
            return false;

        TextF = new RichTextBox(); 

        TextF = To;
        return true;
    }

    private void TextF_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Do something
    }
```

but the thing is that when events in the user's richtextbox are created the eventsmethods on my class are not called even though i have a copy of the user's richtextbox in my class any help

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to connect the event in your `RichTB_Color` class:

```
TextF.TextChanged += TextF_TextChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Line

   ```
   TextF = new RichTextBox();
   ```

   is redundant
2. You need to wire your events to new textbox

Comment: Comment is redundant too - 'if object is null, return false' :-)